# Webpack error when project shared across 2 machines

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have my project saved in a Google Drive folder. It works fine on one of my machines, but on the other I get a bunch of errors when it tries to compile my code. They're all the same error and appear to be related to loading images - here's an example below (the others are all the same, just for different images)

```
    ERROR in ./app/images/profilePics/blankface.jpg
Module build failed: Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at module.exports (/Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/node_modules/execa/index.js:130:26)
    at fsP.writeFile.then (/Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/node_modules/exec-buffer/index.js:35:15)
 @ ./app/admin/components/SideMenu.js 53:12-61
```

It only seems to apply to image loaders - I'm not getting any other errors.

Here's my config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var mainPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'main.js');

var config = {

    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
    },
    entry: [

        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        'whatwg-fetch',
        //Our application
        mainPath
    ],
    output: {
        path: '/',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        //assetsPublicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: nodeModulesPath
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules!postcss?sourceMap'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                  'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                  'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src'
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.mp4$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4'
            }

        ]
    },
    postcss: [
        require('autoprefixer'),
        require('precss')
    ],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `npm install` to make sure that you have all of the loaders that you need installed?

Comment: Yep, done. Both machines running same version of node, webpack and have run npm install to make sure all package dependencies are up to date

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you make sure that all your loaders are listed in the package.json dependencies? I have definitely done that before.

Comment: Yep - everything is installed. The files are actually stored in a Google Drive folder and shared across the two machines, so all of the locally installed dependencies should be exactly the same. Even so, I've run npm install on both machines to double check

Comment: Just to update, some of the errors seem to have disappeared after checking updates and running npm install but there are still some remaining. I have edited the error message above to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm.. seems like a permissions error. Can you double check that you have full RWX permissions in the google drive folder on both machines? You may have to run webpack from a shell that is being run as an administrator.

Comment: Brilliant, that's fixed it! Set all RWX permissions to 777 and it's working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad you got it resolved =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module build failed: Error: spawn EACCES, That is a problem of permissions.